# Why in these matrices are $AB=BA$ not equal? What is the logic behind them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education, matrix-rank

We know that in matrices AB=BA.Why in this Matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3\\
 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\
-3 & -5\end{bmatrix}$ are not equal to $AB=BA$. WHY? This is matrix  of order $2\times 2$ for both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Where do you "know" $AB = BA$ from? Because that isn't true, just as your example shows.

Comment: @Arthur  Do you try it i want to know logic behind them because im a teacher

Comment: Whether you're a teacher or not, we don't know that $AB=BA$.  We know that $AB=BA$ for **numbers**.  We know that it isn't generally true for matrices.  There is no reason that something that is true for one mathematical structure should be true for another.

Comment: There is no «logic behind them». The two matrices AB and BA are not equal and that's it. You would probably not go asking what is the logic behind Batman and Superman not being equal (and there is no reason to treat matrices differently that superheroes, really)

Comment: Can you clarify why you think $AB=BA$ is true in the first place? Also, note that there are other kinds of objects where multiplication is defined, but not commutative - e.g. the **quaternions**. Commutativity of multiplication is a very special property, which happens to hold of the real numbers but need not hold of more general objects (see also the notion of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))).

Comment: "We know that in matrices AB=BA" We know no such thing at all!!!!! In fact, we very distinctly know that that is absolutely **NOT** true.  It' should have been taught to you on the first day that multiplication of matrices is **NOT** commutative.  It is very often the first example of non-commutative multiplication a student comes across.  AB = BA is just NOT TRUE.

Comment: We know that 2+3=7.  Yet 2+3 is not equal to 7!  Why?  What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply isn't true that $AB = BA$, except in very special cases, such as if both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.

For instance, for general $2\times 2$ matrices $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $B = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}r&s\\t&u\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ we have
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}ar + bt & as + bu\\cr + dt & cs + du\end{bmatrix}
$$
while
$$
BA = \begin{bmatrix}ar + cs & br + ds\\at + cu & bt + du\end{bmatrix}
$$
and you can clearly see that there are loads of choices for $a, b, c, d, r, s, t, u$ that makes these two matrices different.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what matrices "do".

For example: the matrix
$$
A := \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
stretches the $x$-axis by a factor of two, and the matrix
$$
B := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
rotates everything $90^\circ$ anti-clockwise.

Thus 
$$
B A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
first stretches the $x$ component of the vector $(1, 0)^T$ then rotates,
whereas
$$
A B \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
first rotates and then stretches the $x$ component.

You can convince yourself that the resulting point is not the same in the two cases. This means that $B A \neq A B$.

Comment: +1. Additional context for the OP: here, we're viewing 2-by-2 matrices as representing *linear transformations* on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The fact that we can do this is definitely not obvious, but is true; see any book on linear algebra for details.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is generally not commutative unless they're both equal or they're inverses (in which case you will obtain the identity).

Comment: Just FYI, there are other cases too. I wouldn't say "unless".

Comment: The "unless" exception is too restrictive. What if $B=I$ and $A\ne B$? They are not equal and not inverses. Another example $B=0$ and $A\ne B$.

Comment: There are a lot more cases when matrices commute. For instance, if one of the matrices is diagonalisable, then the two commute iff the other is diagonalisable in the same basis.

Comment: Two matrices commute if they have the same eigenspaces even if their eigenvalues differ. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

You can think of matrices as linear transformations.  For example, let $T$ be the map which rotates a point ninety degrees counterclockwise.  It is the function from the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself given by the formula $(x,y) \mapsto (-y,x)$.  It is represented by the matrix $$A  =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

in the sense that if you want to compute what $T$ does to a point $v = (x,y)$, just compute the matrix product $Av^{\textrm{tr}}$, where here $v^{\textrm{tr}}$ means $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$.

On the other hand, consider the function $S$ which takes a point $(x,y)$ and reflects it across the $x$-axis, giving you the point $(x,-y)$.  It is represented by the matrix $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ *Under the interpretation of matrices as functions from the plane to itself, the composition $T \circ S$ (that is, $S$ followed by $T$) corresponds to the matrix product $AB$, and $S \circ T$ corresponds to the matrix product $BA$.*

But it is intuitively obvious that $T \circ S$ and $S \circ T$ are not the same function: rotating a point ninety degrees counterclockwise, and then reflecting it across the $x$-axis, usually does not do the same thing as first reflecting the point across the $x$-axis, and then rotating it ninety degrees.  Since $T \circ S \neq S \circ T$, we cannot expect to have $AB = BA$, and you can indeed check that these matrices are not equal.